# 'Selector' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, database, web-scraping, scrapy, data-mining

I've a problem with my data mining project at scrapy. I have this error message when I run my spider and ı really don't know how can I fix this please help me!

> This is error output

```
2021-01-08 21:27:41 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET 
https://yokatlas.yok.gov.tr/content/lisans-dynamic/1000_1.php?y=100110027> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
yield next(it)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 347, in __next__
return next(self.data)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 347, in __next__
return next(self.data)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
for r in iterable:
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\offsite.py", line 29, in 
process_spider_output
for x in result:
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
for r in iterable:
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\referer.py", line 340, in <genexpr>
return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
for r in iterable:
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
for r in iterable:
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spidermiddlewares\depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\spidermw.py", line 64, in _evaluate_iterable
for r in iterable:
File "C:\Users\yusuf\Desktop\Yök Atlas Projesi\atlasdatas\atlasdatas\spiders\atlasspider.py", line 
46, in parse
items["ÖSYM_KODU"] = ÖSYM_KODU
TypeError: 'Selector' object does not support item assignment
2021-01-08 21:27:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2021-01-08 21:27:41 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 712,
'downloader/request_count': 3,
'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
'downloader/response_bytes': 27358,
'downloader/response_count': 3,
'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
'downloader/response_status_count/302': 1,
'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.978011,
'finish_reason': 'finished',
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 8, 18, 27, 41, 343786),
'log_count/DEBUG': 36,
'log_count/ERROR': 1,
'log_count/INFO': 10,
'response_received_count': 2,
'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
'spider_exceptions/TypeError': 1,
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 8, 18, 27, 40, 365775)}
2021-01-08 21:27:41 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

> My Spider.py file

```
import scrapy
from atlasdatas.items import AtlasdatasItem

class Atlasdatas(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "atlas"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['https://yokatlas.yok.gov.tr/content/lisans-dynamic/1000_1.php?y=100110027']             
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):
        items = AtlasdatasItem()
        parse_place = response.css("table.table-bordered")
        for items in parse_place:
           
            #PROGRAM_İSMİ = items.css("big::text")[0].getall()
           
            ÖSYM_KODU = items.css("td.text-center::text")[0].get()
            ÜNİVERSİTE_TÜRÜ = items.css("td.text-center::text")[1].get()
            ÜNİVERSİTE_İSMİ = items.css("td.text-center::text")[2].get()
            FAKÜLTE_YÜKSEKOKUL = items.css("td.text-center::text")[3].get()
            PUAN_TÜRÜ = items.css("td.text-center::text")[4].get()
            BURS_TÜRÜ = items.css("td.text-center::text")[5].get()
           
            #items["PROGRAM_İSMİ"] = PROGRAM_İSMİ

            items["ÖSYM_KODU"] = ÖSYM_KODU
            items["ÜNİVERSİTE_TÜRÜ"] = ÜNİVERSİTE_TÜRÜ
            items["ÜNİVERSİTE_İSMİ"] = ÜNİVERSİTE_İSMİ
            items["FAKÜLTE_YÜKSEKOKUL"] = FAKÜLTE_YÜKSEKOKUL
            items["PUAN_TÜRÜ"] = PUAN_TÜRÜ
            items["BURS_TÜRÜ"] = BURS_TÜRÜ
            yield items
```

> and My items.py file which datas will be save in sqlite3 database

```
import scrapy

class AtlasdatasItem(scrapy.Item):

    #PROGRAM_İSMİ = scrapy.Field()

    ÖSYM_KODU = scrapy.Field()
    ÜNİVERSİTE_TÜRÜ = scrapy.Field()
    ÜNİVERSİTE_İSMİ = scrapy.Field()
    FAKÜLTE_YÜKSEKOKUL = scrapy.Field()
    PUAN_TÜRÜ = scrapy.Field()
    BURS_TÜRÜ = scrapy.Field()
```

> And my pipelines.py file

```
import sqlite3

class AtlasDB(object):

    def __init__(self):
       self.create_connection()
       self.create_table()
    
    def create_connection(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("atlasdb")
        self.curr = self.conn.cursor()
    
    def create_table(self):
        self.curr.execute(
            """CREATE TABLE GENERAL_INF(
            
            OSYM_KODU INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
            ÜNİVERSİTE_TÜRÜ TEXT,
            ÜNİVERSİTE_İSMİ TEXT,
            FAKÜLTE_YÜKSEKOKUL TEXT,
            PUAN_TÜRÜ TEXT,
            BURS_TÜRÜ TEXT)"""
        )
    def process_ıtems(self,item,spider):
        self.store_db(item)
        return item
    
    def store_db(self,item):
        self.curr.execute("""INSERT INTO VALUES
        
        GENERAL_INF values (?,?,?,?,?,?)""",(
             item["ÖSYM_KODU"][0],
             item["ÜNİVERSİTE_TÜRÜ"][0],
             item["ÜNİVERSİTE_İSMİ"][0],
             item["FAKÜLTE_YÜKSEKOKUL"][0],
             item["PUAN_TÜRÜ"][0],
             item["BURS_TÜRÜ"][0]
         ))
        self.conn.commit()
        return item
```

What should ı do this situation please help me

Comment: I tried it but didn't work :(

Comment: A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could get you more feedback, or even help you figure out the issue for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You have a different spellling of "OSYM_KODU" in pipelines.py

Can you make that the same as "ÖSYM_KODU" as it is spelled everywhere else and try again?